# Self-reference not working on Flask (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy to create a web app and I'm having troubles with self-reference. On my project I have companies (model), a company can have a provider (another company) or not. If one company is a provider, that company should have a list of clients (every company that it provides services).

Using SQLAlchemy Documentation I've tried to make this self-reference relationship.

This are my models:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db

class Organization(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    rut = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='organization', lazy=True)

class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    provider_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=True)
    clients = db.relationship('Company', remote_side=[id])
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='company', lazy=False)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    organization_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organization.id'), nullable=False)
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'), nullable=True)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

The problem is that, even though I can register the provider_id (provider company) I cannot relate this with the clients field on the provider object. So If I have this company #1 which is company #2's provider, and I check the company #1's clients it's empty. Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?
This is my first time working with Flask and SQLAlchemy.
And I need to set up the list of clients because to delete companies I want to be able to delete just the ones with no clients.

Comment: I think you'd find [this chapter](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-viii-followers) of the Flask Mega Tutorial useful. You don't have an association table or a `secondaryjoin`

Comment: Although, I'll grant that I've only just discovered `remote_side` so perhaps that is a step backwards in fixing this